# consejos sobre instalacion de drupal

Tags: drupal

buenas! chicos, alguien podría ayudarme por favor? quiero instalar drupal en mi computadora, pero quiero hacerlo sin utilizar acquia ni xampp, tengo php instalado globalmente en mi pc al igual que mysql.
necesito saber como instalar drupal usando php y mysql, instalados globlamente, y adicional a eso, como correr un servidor que ejecute ese proyecto drupal.
¿alguien, puede ayudarme? urgente...

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por mas que digas que es urgente, no vas a conseguir respuestas mas rapido. Deberias aclarar porque no podes utilizar ninguno de los metodos comunes o en particular esos metodos que decis que no, para que podamos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Gracias. en parte no deseo usar los métodos mencionados ya que como dije anteriormente tengo php y mysql instalados globalmente, al instalar las herramientas como acquia o xampp me genera un error en esa parte ya, que tengo instalados esos componentes. y no deseo desinstalarlos.
por ejemplo, probe con xampp y me genero un conflicto el Mysql, debido a que ya está instalado en mi pc.

Comment: Primero tendrás que ver si las versiones que tienes de MySQL y PHP son soportadas por la versión de Drupal que vayas a instalar. Y necesitarás un servidor web, apache es el más habitual pero te vale cualquiera que soporte PHP. Aquí no te vamos a hacer un tutorial de instalación, tendrás que seguir los pasos de la documentación y si tienes algún problema concreto puedes hacer una pregunta

Answer (score 0):

En principio lo que deberías hacer es instalar Apache Web Server o bien Nginx para que puedas deployar tu aplicación allí, con deployar me refiero básicamente a copiar los fuentes de tu proyecto en la carpeta indicada para cada servidor (Ej. Apache: /var/www/html/tuproyecto si usas linux como SO host) ir a un navegador como Chrome y escribir localhost/tuproyecto y verificar que el servidor esta instalado y corriento en tu PC.

Si me pasas mas detalles quiza te pueda ayudar un poco más !

- Tipo de SO: Windows o Linux y otro.
- Version de Drupal: Drupal 7 o Drupal 8.
- Otros componentes que requieras utilizar.

Te dejo algunos links que te pueden ayudar

**Instalar Apache en windows:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6Mgdj2Gp5E

**Instalar Apache en Linux:** https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-en-ubuntu-18-04-la-pila-lamp-linux-apache-mysql-y-php-es

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como te comenta Juan Pablo, la mejor opción siempre es tener un apache, nginx... instalado que te permita depurar el código de una manera más sencilla.

Si como comentas no te interesa la instalación del servidor pues puedes optar por:

- Ejecutar el servidor que trae php integrado en la carpeta dónde guardas tu proyecto (https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.commandline.webserver.php)
- O hacer uso de Docker con una imagen que puedas lanzar que incluya todo lo necesario para depurar código, realización de test, codesniffer para Drupal...

Answer (score 0):

### Guía de Drupal en ambiente de desarrollo local con Docker

Lo más recomendable sería usar un ambiente de desarrollo local basado en contenedores como DDEV, Lando, Docksal, Docker4Drupal, etc. Hay varias opciones, pero si sigues la guía de desarrollo local encontrada en la documentación oficial de Drupal, puedes encontrar una guía que te ayuda a implementar un sitio de Drupal usando DDEV: [Guía de desarrollo local con DDEV](https://www.drupal.org/docs/official_docs/en/_local_development_guide.html)